# Do I need libmilter somewhere to make postfix use dkim-filter?

Tags: postfix, milter

I've been doing everything the instructions say http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html and I was able to build, configure and run dkim-filter but postfix doesn't seem to call it.

I've got this in my main.cf

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = unix:/etc/postfix/dkim-filter.sock
```

and I set dkim-filter to read from that same file descriptor, no errors anywhere, but I don't get any dkim headers in the mail I send through postfix. Is there something else I have to turn on?

This is on solaris 10. postfix 2.3.20060611

Comment: I think I just figured out my problem. wikipedia says: Milter support was added to Postfix 2.3.0 released July 12, 2006 I'm a month early. :-(

Comment: okay we upgraded to 2.8 still nothing. Why no love from milter?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I got it to answer. I am sending a message via smtp to postfix, yet it only worked when I added the non_smtpd_milters entry to main.cf not just smtpd_milters.

Lesson learned there.